# Java: for loop executes once even after interruption of current thread

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

i am new to the threading concept. I was trying to interrupt the current thread inside run().

Basically, i was trying to print out a word 5 times (in a for loop) with 2s sleep in between. When i try to interrupt the thread before the 2nd time the loop executes, i still get the word printed out the 2nd time.

```
public void run()
{
try{
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
 //print word
 System.out.println(word);
 //sleep
  Thread.sleep(2000);
 //interrupt
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

 }
 } catch(InterruptedException e){
 System.out.println("sleep interrupted");
 }
}
```

However, when i compile and run the code, i get the following result:

```
word
word
sleep interrupted
```

I was expecting the word to be printed only once as the interrupt was called before looping to the next instance of the for loop. I don't understand why the 2nd word and InterruptedException "sleep interrupted" gets thrown at the same time..

I was expecting interrupt to throw "sleep interrupted" without printing the word the 2nd time.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't check the interrupted flag; so interrupting does nothing. _next time_ you call `sleep`, then it checks the flag and the exception is raised.

Comment: extending the comment of @BoristheSpider: to get the desired behaviour, you would have to interrupt the thread from an external source (another thread).

Comment: @Turing85 Interrupting from an external source still wouldn't interrupt *immediately*. If the thread is currently executing the `i++` at the time another thread call `interrupt()`, you'd still see the same behavior.

Comment: @Andreas you are right. To be exact, one would have to interrupt the thread before or while it is executing the `sleep(...)` in the first iteration. This was a silent assumption I did not mention, but notices it too late, so I wasn't able to edit my comment :)

Comment: Thanks everyone for explaining it to me! really appreciate it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the javadoc of [`interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29):

> If this thread is blocked [...]
>
> If this thread is blocked [...]
>
> If this thread is blocked [...]
>
> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's **interrupt status will be set**.

Since your thread is not blocked at the time you call `interrupt()`, it just sets the status, without throwing an exception.

The `sleep()` method then detects the interrupt status and throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

- first time prints word
- sleeps 2 seconds
- interrupt() called
- second time print word
- call to sleep throws InterruptedException

What you want is

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 5 && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted(); i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call Thread.currentThread().interrupt(), you set the interrupt flag of the thread, which then can be used by higher level interrupt handlers appropriately. Usually, people use this when they catch InterruptedException, ie., inside the catch block to let the caller know that an interrupt has occurred.

But here, you use that to exit the for loop. And the flag set is realized by the program when you enter Thread.Sleep() the second time around. To read it manually,

Try this

```
for(int i=0;i<=5 && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();i++)
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: there you go. all better.

Comment: sure. glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your are not actually interrupting your thread when calling [`interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) .

So, your exception is triggered on its **second**, after interrupting, when status has been set to interrupt. In this status, you are not allowed to sleep, so you get the exception.